# Function should return resultset when executed in select statement

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, resultset

I'm trying to write a pl/sql function that returns a resultset table that I can retrieve using a select statement.

Here is what I got so far:

Type REF CURSOR:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE types
AS
TYPE ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
END;
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getitems
    RETURN types.ref_cursor
AS
    mycursor types.ref_cursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN mycursor FOR 
        SELECT myid, myname, mytype 
        FROM mycategory;
    RETURN mycursor;
END getitems;
```

Select statement:

```
SELECT getitems() FROM dual;
```

This is almost(!) what I wanted. The only problem now is that Selecting From dual resulted in exactly one entry in the resultset, this entry being the table I really wanted.

How do I get the select statement to unwrap the the outer resultset and deliver just the inner table so I can cursor along the inner table?

Answer (score 0):

You can't query a `REF CURSOR`. A possible solution is to use `PIPELINED function` and `TABLE` function (read more here: [Tim Hall about PIPELINED functions](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php)). Example:

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
  id NUMBER,
  name VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO emp VALUES (1, 'Smith');
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (2, 'Brown');

COMMIT;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE emp_row_t AS OBJECT (
  id NUMBER,
  name VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE emp_tab_t IS TABLE OF emp_row_t;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION piped_function RETURN emp_tab_t PIPELINED AS
BEGIN
  FOR v_rec IN (SELECT id, name FROM emp)
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW (emp_row_t(v_rec.id, v_rec.name));
  END LOOP;
END;

-- and now query using that function
SELECT id, name FROM TABLE(piped_function);
```

Check at SQLFiddle: <kbd>[SQLFiddle PIPELINED function example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1f0e4/1)</kbd>